# ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

When I am try to submit my app to app store, I am getting the error:

> **ERROR ITMS-90685**: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than
>   one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value
>   com.companyname.projectName under the application ProjectName.app"

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 50):

### Cause

It happens if your HostApp embeds a framework which has been also embedded in some of the frameworks which are also being embedded in HostApp. For example,

1. Host `H` embeds framework `F1` and framework `F2`
2. Framework `F1` embeds framework `F2`
3. Thus, Framework `F2` will be duplicated in bundle after IPA generated

### Solution

Only HostApp but no other frameworks should embed any dependent frameworks in their respective Build Phase. So,

1. Go to Build Phase tab for `F1`
2. Remove `F2` from `Embed Frameworks` step, or remove full step
3. Go to General tab for `F1`
4. Select Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content
5. Select `Do Not Embed` option for `F2`

Have a clean build.

Comment: I did not need to make changes in Build Phase settings. I only needed to select the `Do Not Embed` option for all of the frameworks listed under `General` settings for each of my framework and app extension targets.

Comment: For me there is no option "Do Not Embed".  I've adde amplify framework to my project using SPM.  I need this in my share extension also so I went to share extension general and 'Frameworks and Libraries' and manually added the libraries.  It builds and runs but cannot archive with collision error.  The solutions here don't seem to work for me because I have no option 'do not embed' next to the libraries.

Comment: This solution works for duplicated frameworks, but SPM dependencies end up being static libs, and you can't "not embed" those.

Comment: Is there also a solution for SPM / static libs? I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes this doesn't have anything to do with App Extensions, in an app without any App Extension this can be originated because you're duplicating a framework inside the generated IPA.

In my case the issue was I was importing a framework A that contained other two frameworks B & C, all in the same workspace. In the app I was importing A, B, C but in the framework A the frameworks B & C were embedded with the **Embed & sign** and that's incorrect and it was causing the issue. It should have been added with the **Do not embed**.

Comment: You would have thought xcode would warn before uploading to itms stage!

Comment: Thanks, this answer was solving my problem!

Comment: I cannot set do not embed for xcframework and I am stuck. I use alamofire and ziparchive in the framework and in the app as well. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm running into this with dependencies that end up being static libraries, and you can't set those to Do Not Embed.

Answer (score 7):

Steps without script:

- Open the (Your App).xcodeproj file (this is the first file on the project navigator pane).
- Switch to the target for your app extension (on the top left of the middle pane).
- Go to the Build Phases tab
- Click the X after "Embed Pod Frameworks"

Comment: Helped.

The reason is: Only the first uploaded project would need to have *"Pod Frameworks"*.

After that, the rest of them with the same identifier will take the libraries from the first one.

Comment: Also works with SPM. SPM's library should be marked as `.dynamic`.

Comment: How to mark SPM library as .dynamic?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a long standing bug that is even present with Swift Package Manager. For the build phase of the extensions, I added this "Run Script" as the last step:

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
    rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

This removes the duplicate framework it's complaining about during archiving, which will be linked from the host target anyway. We just need it to be linked in Xcode for the extension so we can compile at development time.

Comment: Nothing else has worked for me so I'm trying this solution for a package added using SPM but I've never used scripts before.  So I went to my extension Build Phases pressed the plus to add run script and pasted your above code unchanged.  But error is still there.  Is there something more I need to do to add this script?

Comment: This script does not work for me neither. Maybe there is some mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Have you got an App Extension in your app?
I had this error because of Cocoapods embedded frameworks inside App Extension folder.

You need to remove build phase `'[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'` from Extension target.

I wrote such ruby script for that:

```
# remove.rb
require 'xcodeproj'

project_path = "Keyboard.xcodeproj"
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
project.targets.each do |target|
    puts target.name
    if target.name.include?("Extension")
        phase = target.shell_script_build_phases.find { |bp| bp.name == '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' }
        if !phase.nil?
            puts "Deleting Embed Pods Frameworks phase from #{target.name}…"
            target.build_phases.delete(phase)
        end
    end
end

project.save
```

In **CocoaPods 1.1.0** that should be fixed: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4203

Answer (score 2):

If you have an App Extension, make sure it's bundle identifier is distinct from your app's bundle identifier.

Example:

Does not work

```
App Bundle Identifier: company.myApp  
Extension Bundle Identifier: company.myApp
```

Works

```
App Bundle Identifier: company.myApp  
Extension Bundle Identifier: company.myApp.extension
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Isenman, say the extension bundle identifier is com.xyz.abc , what is your suggested "Works" Extension Bundle Identifier? I've tried com.myapp.xyz.abc and iterations and can't get it to work

Comment: This worked for me so thank you. Unbelievable a company like Apple has a bug like that with minimal documentation

Answer (score 1):

**For Frameworks managed by SPM**

The solution is to create a shared Framework. Create a Framework in Xcode and move all the shared (static) SPM dependencies to the shared framework you just created and remove all of them from any other targets you've previously added to. And then add the new framework you just created (Shared framework) to the targets that need them. Make sure to select `Do Not Embed`. and in the host app `Embed and Sign`