# "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.cocoapods.FMDB'

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, app-store, cocoapods

I have a pod file

```
target 'MainApp' do  # the host app target
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xxxxxx
   ....
  pod 'FMDB', '2.6.2'
   ......
end

target 'CallExtension3' do  # the Extension target whose host app is MainApp
   platform :ios, '10.0'
    # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for CallExtension3
    pod 'FMDB', '2.6.2''
end
```

Build and archive is OK. But when I submit app to app store, there is error.

```
ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.cocoapods.FMDB' under the iOS application 'xxxxxx.app'."
```

How to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005130/error-itms-90685-cfbundleidentifier-collision-there-is-more-than-one-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4203
may be can help you

or Click on extension in target section -> Build phases -> remove the embed pods frameworks

Comment: You may like to include some reproducible code snip in your answer too...