# I can't submit my app to appStore(Error ERROR ITMS-90685, ERROR ITMS-90347)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've got two errors that I can't find a solution. If you guys have any idea, please let me know. Thanks a lot

ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value '-----' under the iOS application '----.app'."

ERROR ITMS-90347: "Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier '-----' of the application extension -----.app/PlugIns/Notification.appex should start with the application's bundle identifier '-----' and not contain more than one period “.” after the application's bundle ID."

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005130/error-itms-90685-cfbundleidentifier-collision-there-is-more-than-one-bundle

Comment: It didn't help, thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **first error**: Make sure that the bundle ID is unique. Check both [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) and [Apple Developer center](https://developer.apple.com/account) if there are similar bundle IDs in your team.

Recommended scheme is "reverse domain name", e.g. `com.apple.keynote`

Solution for **second error**: App extensions must include the bundle ID of the "parent" app. So from the previous example the bundle ID of the app extension would look like `com.apple.keynote.NameOfExtension`

Other things to note: version + build code need to be exactly the same between app and app extension.